# Add online album to Android Gallery App

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-gallery

I have a large amount of online images stored on my server. I have created a small java server backend to provide album lists and images per album, including a small management console.

I want to use/view these images on my Android device, by using the standard photo/gallery application. Apps like Google Picasa and Facebook do the same thing.

Eg. When I open up the gallery app, there's a tab called "Albums" where a number of folders are visible, including Picasa/Facebook. Most of these folders can be found on my SD card, but the albums by Picasa/Facebook are only online. Entering these online albums clearly shows the "album structure" you have with that provider ("Profile Pictures" at Facebook for instance).

The question:
How did Picasa/Facebook end up there, and how can I recreate said functionality?
I am almost certain it is done using Content Providers, but I can't even find a simple example when used for images. And unfortunatly, most answers here are providing solutions to the wrong problem.

The secondary question: Would this also be possible with Android's Movie and Music players?